Flutter Firebase mobile auth get session-expired error
With flutter and firebase mobile authentication i get OTP successfully, But when verify this OTP i get error session-expired.
I lots of try to figure out solution on stack-overflow and medium article, but really not work anything.
In some article author say no need to do verificationCompleted method in firebase authentication and some of author navigate from here to home page or OTP verify page (Here i also confuse what actually need to do).
Above both solution i was tried but really not working any of them.
Minimal code what i did

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import '../exported.dart';

class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
  Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber({
    required String phone,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    try {
      isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = true;
      notifyListeners();
      final phoneNumber = '+91 ${phone.substring(0, 4)} ${phone.substring(4, 7)} ${phone.substring(7)}'; // +91 **** *** *** format mobile number

      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,

        //! 120 second maximum timeout duration
        // timeout: const Duration(seconds: 45),
        //! Work in Android for automatically otp detect and sign up
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          // auth.authStateChanges().listen(
          //   (user) {
          //     if (user != null && user.uid.isNotEmpty && context.mounted) {
          //       debugPrint('authStateChanges -------------------> : ${user.uid}');
          //       if (ModalRoute.of(context) != null &&
          //           ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name != null &&
          //           !ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name!.contains(RoutePath.home) &&
          //           (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name!.contains(RoutePath.login) ||
          //               ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name!.contains(RoutePath.otp))) {
          //         onSignInSuccessfully(context);
          //       }
          //     }
          //   },
          // );

          debugPrint('onVerification Auto Completed Work');
          try {
            final UserCredential credential = await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

            isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
            notifyListeners();

        

            if (credential.user != null && credential.user!.uid.isNotEmpty && context.mounted) {
              onSignInSuccessfully(context); // move to home screen 
            }
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.code);
            isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
            notifyListeners();
          } catch (e) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$e');
            isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
            notifyListeners();
          }
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          debugPrint('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout Work');
          debugPrint('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout : $verificationId');

          debugPrint('-------------> ${auth.currentUser?.uid}');

          isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
          notifyListeners();
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? forceResendingToken) {
          debugPrint('codeSent Work');
          isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
          notifyListeners();

          // move to otp screen from below method and then where user will enter otp and call `verifyOTP` (given below) to verify OTP 
          pushNReplace( 
            context: context,
            routeName: RoutePath.otp,
            arguments: verificationId,
          );
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
          isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
          notifyListeners();
          debugPrint('verificationFailed code : ${error.code}');
          debugPrint('verificationFailed phoneNumber : ${error.phoneNumber}');
          debugPrint('verificationFailed message : ${error.message}');

          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.code);
        },
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint('signInWithMobileNumber : FirebaseAuthException : $e');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.code);
    } catch (e) {
      isLoadingForVerifyMobileNumber = false;
      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint('signInWithMobileNumber error : $e');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$e');
    }
  }

  String errorMsg = '';
  bool hasError = false;
  bool isLoadingForVerifyOTP = false;
  bool signInSuccessFully = false;
  Future<bool> verifyOTP({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String smsCode,
  }) async {
    if (smsCode.isEmpty) {
      hasError = true;
      errorMsg = 'Please enter OTP';
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    } else if (smsCode.length < 6) {
      hasError = true;
      errorMsg = 'Please enter entire OTP';
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
      //! Terminate function
    }

    final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );

    isLoadingForVerifyOTP = true;

    notifyListeners();
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      isLoadingForVerifyOTP = false;
      hasError = false;
      errorMsg = '';
      signInSuccessFully = (userCredential.user?.uid ?? "").isNotEmpty;
      notifyListeners();
      return signInSuccessFully;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      isLoadingForVerifyOTP = false;
      hasError = true;
      errorMsg = e.code;
      signInSuccessFully = false;
      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint('verifyOTP : FirebaseError code : ${e.code}');
      debugPrint('verifyOTP : FirebaseError message : ${e.message}');
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      isLoadingForVerifyOTP = false;
      hasError = true;
      errorMsg = 'Something went wrong';
      signInSuccessFully = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  //! SUCCESSFULLY AUTH
  void onSignInSuccessfully(BuildContext context) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SignIn successfully");
    pushNReplace(context: context, routeName: RoutePath.home);
  }

  //! LOGOUT
  bool isLoadingForLogout = false;
  Future<bool> logout() async {
    isLoadingForLogout = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500));
      // add 1.5 second delay
      final isLogOut = auth.currentUser == null;
      isLoadingForLogout = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return isLogOut;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.code);
      isLoadingForLogout = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Something went wrong");
      isLoadingForLogout = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

}




Here i get OTP successfully but get error in otp-verify-screen where i enter received OTP from SMS when i call  verifyOTP method (in above code).
strange when i get session-expired error then i just kill my app (close app) and re-open at that time authentication was done and i auto navigated in home screen, mean authentication must be done in previous process (process before kill my app).
Thank you in advance!
I really need to understand what actually done here
